Is Sheena Barksdale a.k.a 'Cass' from The Wire the actual daughter of the real life Barksdale?
Sheena Barksdale, aka 'Cass' appears in The Wire first season as an uncredited character who is part of D' Angelo Barksdale's crew, however that is her only on screen appearance in the show. The Wire follows the story of Avon Barksdale, portrayed by Wood Harris, who is the leader of the most powerful drug ring in Baltimore. This character is based on Nathan Barksdale, who is actually portrayed by Bodie (another supporting character). Is 'Cass' related to the real life Barksdale?

I'm confused. Are you asking whether Cass the character is related to the fictional Barksdales, or whether Sheena Barksdale the actress is related to the real-life Barksdales?

@F1Krazy - He's asking if she has any family connection to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_Barksdale or the Barksdale family, a reputed crime family in Baltimore.

"Sheena is a Native Baltimorean & a true working artist. She a trained actress, natural hair stylist & holistic massage art therapist. She is an alum of St. Frances Academy  and a proud HBCU grad. Sheena got her acting start with the Mamas of Wombwork Productions, Inc., in their youth theater ensemble. From there she went to the historic Coppin State University, to major in Urban Arts & Production with a concentration in acting. There she studied under the well-known Professor Amini V. Courts" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xy5-8h1LxXo

Based on her bio she was an aspiring child actress before she was cast on the show, albeit this is her first TV credit. She was in various theatrical productions, largely focused on the African-American experience in Baltimore.

Simon has stated that the characters aren't especially based on any one person. He's just jumbled up a bunch of names of local hoodlums.

According to research on some genealogy sites and others about the real Barksdale and about Sheena, nothing related. He didn't have children too as far as it's known.
